# Standard Matrix Representation for a Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Just did this with $3$ previous problems, but am unsure how to go about this particular one:

$L$ reflects each vector $x$ about the line $x_2 = x_1$ and then projects it onto the x_1-axis.

I understood rotating and reflecting vectors, but what is the line $x_2 = x_1$?

Comment: Assuming you are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$. it is same as the line $y=x$. So you are first reflecting the vector about this line and then projecting it onto $x-$axis. $(a,b) \to (b,a) \to (b,0)$.

Comment: What space is the operator acting on? $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yeah, the dimension wasn't given, but previous problems have used $R^2$ so I'm assuming it is in $R^2$. So when you project onto a certain axis, does that automatically make all x2=0?

Comment: @Chris Projection onto a axis means isolating the coordinate corresponding to that axis and making other coordinates $0$. So if you are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then projection onto the $i^{\text{th}}$ axis will mean sending $(x_1,x_2, \ldots ,x_i, \ldots x_n) \to (0,0, \ldots ,x_i, \ldots 0) $.